# Html heading and link in the same line

Tags: html, css

I am new to css. I want to display a heading h2 in the center and a link in the right end in the same line.

I tried a few options, but all of them align the heading to the left.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few ways you can do this. The simplest and quickest way that I can think of is using a parent div and putting the heading and link inside it. So your HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <h2>Heading comes here</h2><a href="">Link comes here</a>
</div>
```

Your styles can be as follows:

```
.test {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<h1>heading <a href="#">link</a></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
h1 a{
    float:right;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/KJSmB/